# determining Induced emf/current through v x B . l

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, inductance

I am working on a question from my book. I am wondering how they conclude emf is negative in this case. looking at $$ \mathcal{E} = \vec{v} \times \vec{B} \cdot \vec{dl}$$ If there's some implied direction of the rod's direction a->b ($\hat{down}$) then the dot product would result in a negative (since $\vec{v} \times \vec{B}$ is $\hat{up}$). But is that really suppose to be implied? Am I missing something trivial?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $q(\vec v\times \vec B)$ gives the direction of the magnetic component of the lorentz force on the positive charges(electrons feel the force in opposite direction). The emf $(e)$ that is induced must, in equilibrium, create a force on there charges in a direction opposite to the magnetic force given by the cross product. Therefore, the induced field $\vec E$, will be in a direction opposite to the $\vec v\times \vec B$. The emf will be given by $\int \vec E.\vec{dl}$, which will thus be negative with respect to the direction of cross product (taken as positive).

Comment: I almost came to this conclusion before I made this thread but happened to misread something right before, which threw me off. Is it fair to say that induction from Lenz creates an opposite of ANY effect? I had only seen it applied to currents/magnetic fields

Comment: In most cases the *opposition* is confined to the induced fields only.The currents follow the field always, but they may be in opposition to the magnetic force acting on them. However, the best way to tackle such problems is to consider the direction of induced current such as to create a magnetic field in a direction opposite to the *change* in the external magnetic field.